# Import and process real time sensor data of heartbeat in R

Tags: r, real-time, sensors

I am trying to build a model in R that takes real time input(heartbeat) from a sensor and perform an operation when the value of heartbeat goes beyond a baseline value. Is there way to get the real time data from sensor in R directly or indirectly?

I will use Windows server 2008 R2 with 32 GB memory and 12 cores. I am planning to use data(total 3 bytes, 1 for unique ID and 2 for data) from watch that I custom designed and process that into R. Basically send a notification(email) to user when his/her heartbeat goes beyond a baseline value. Can this be possible in R? Can the input data be received in real time in R in any way or form? What other languages/platform do you recommend for this kind of project?

Any recommendation for databases(AWS, oracle, Apache...) to use for data collection?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to answer the question you're asking without a *lot* more information on things like the hardware platform, operating system, and how the sensor data is provided to the OS, among other things. Additionally, I don't believe that R is generally a good choice for real-time applications.

Comment: I will use Windows server 2008 R2 with 32 GB memory and 12 cores. I am planning to use data from watches like Fitbit or Empitica and process that into R. Basically send a notification(email) to user when his/her heartbeat goes beyond a baseline value. Can this be possible in R? Can the input data be received in real time in R in any way or form? What other languages/platform do you recommend for this kind of project?

Comment: Provide some sample data  ....... and please  .... read the help pages and use the [edit] function that SO so kindly provides.

Comment: You could use a plain text file as interface, that would deal with buffering and concurrency issues.

Comment: Thank you David for the input. I will post more questions when I move further in this project and after completion I will share all the work and code on my GitHub.